# Testing multicasting on my kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, multicast

I have linux kernel 3.14.28. i enabled multicasting to that kernel(config_ip_multicast=y,config_ip_router=y,config_ip_mroute=y, config_ip_ipip=y). finally my new kernel was build successfully and the kernel was UP. now how can i check multicasting on my imx6Q wandboard.

thanks for your comments

Comment: `how can i check multicasting` - Do you want to verify, whether **parameters** you have give to the kernel **are actually in effect**? Or you want some ready testsuite, which allows you to verify, whether **implementation of multicasting on your board is correct**?

Comment: i want to verify whether parameters given to the kernel are actually in effect. please tell me about commands that i can perform on my new kernel(how to assign an IP addr to a multicast network?, how to add other devices to that multicast network?)

Answer (score 0):

**The question is not clear enough.**

I'll try my best any way.

Sending multicast messages is used by the usual UTP datagram API just to a certain range of IP's.

For receiving multicast, you need to join a multicast group using IGMP join message and wait on the socket.

BTW -
The kernel doesn't handle multicast routing on it's own. a user space daemon must support it. check for mrouted, pimd or smcroute.

Comment: ok i'll change my question, to set a broadcast address we use the command                  sudo ifconfig eth0 <system_ip> broadcast <broadcast_addr_224.0.0.0--239.255.255.255>. how to set an ip address to a multicast network, is there any specific command to set a multicast network address